# PowerShell script to install multiple programs, report install successful or failed

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script to install multiple programs on a machine, but I want it to report if the install was successful or failed.

I have no experience with PowerShell and have tried everything I could find on StackOverflow and Google but it doesn't make sense to me.

```
$install = Start-Process -FilePath "path" -ArgumentList "/qb" -Wait
if ($install.ExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Install Successful"
} else {
    Write-Host "Install Failed"
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question. What did you expect the code to do? What does it actually do (i.e. what doesn't work the way you expected)?

Comment: well as stated i want it to install multiple programs, and report if each install was successful and or failed, it installs the program but it doesn't tell me if its failed or successful.

Comment: Try `Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList 'your.msi', '/qn', '/l*v C:\msi.log' -Wait`. Does that help? If not, does `C:\msi.log` give you any pointers afterwards?

Comment: it just creates a log file, this isn't what i want, i want it to tell me that it installed successfully after the program finished installing like i can get it to in a batch file. or if there was an issue and it didn't install it would tell me install failed like if there was an error. 

in batch all i have to do is call "path" "switches"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :Failed-1
echo Install Complete!
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO :install 1

but in powershell its not as simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the parameter `-PassThru` to `Start-Process`, so that the cmdlet actually outputs a process object that you can assign to the variable `$install`. The code you have doesn't do that, so `$install` is empty and checking a property `ExitCode` on an empty variable obviously won't do what you expect. You may also want to use `/qn` (no UI) instead of `/qb` (basic UI) for an unattended install.

This should do what you want:

```
$install = Start-Process -FilePath 'path' -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait -PassThru
if ($install.ExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Install Successful"
} else {
    Write-Host "Install Failed"
}
```

With that said, it's clearly not possible that the code posted in your question would have given you no output at all. It *should* have displayed "Install Failed" regardless of whether or not the install was successful because with `$install` being empty `$install.ExitCode -eq 0` would have evaluated to `$null -eq 0`, which in turn evaluates to `$false`.

Comment: this is perfect, i use the qb cause i don't like the silent install, i need to see some kind of progression bar so that i can see that its doing something.,  thanks you for your help.